# Excel Shifting the text in the bar

Tags: excel, formatting

I have created a calendar which marks the weeks via a conditional formatting.

If I change the calendar weeks in `column A` and `column B`, the yellow bar from `column D` is automatically moved.

The problem here is that the text doesn't move with it. How can I achieve this?

The shifting of the live bar is done with a conditional formatting, which includes the `AND()` formula.

I hope the example image helps:

Calendar example

[image]

Comment: What does it mean by `W,K,F,B,B,A`. Suppose you select 45 to 52 in then what text you expect to column D to next columns....?

Comment: Use an if() with the same formula ie logic you use for the conditional formatting then return either the text or blank.

Comment: The terms are arbitrarily chosen and are abbreviations for certain processes

If I choose calendar week 45 to 52, the text has to move along with it

Comment: @Harun24HR do you have an idea how can implement this?